# How to delete an object using javascript in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I want to do the delete operation by javascript with a confirmation window.
How to do it?

```
<div class="card-footer">
            <a href="{% url 'course_delete' student.slug %}"><button>Delete</button></a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event in javascript onclick then you can use confirm window javascript

```
<div class="card-footer">
            <a href="{% url 'course_delete' student.slug %}" onclick='confirm("Press a button!");'><button>Delete</button></a>
        </div>
```